# 500 internal server error after modify css

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a website build with laravel and Vuejs is new i have done yesterday and i have put him on domain.
After a long day(war) i have found who upload my file correctly and modify .htaccess for working fine.

But i have a litle update my project only css !

So i delete on server my website and upload new website but now i got a error :)

So on website i got that :

```
Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

Now my log server error is that :

```
[Wed Mar 25 16:55:59 2020] [alert] [client 2a01:cb15:fe:8100:d6c:1aa0:83e3:13ca] [host www.mywebsite.com] /homez.964/rolletrade/www/.htaccess: </IfModule> without matching <IfModule> section

[Wed Mar 25 16:55:59 2020] [alert] [client 2a01:cb15:fe:8100:d6c:1aa0:83e3:13ca] [host www.mywebsite.com] /homez.964/rolletrade/www/.htaccess: </IfModule> without matching <IfModule> section
```

So what i have doing ? i have right all step the time is working so i do the same but is not working..

1: Drop all project in filezilla main folder "www"
2: I go in myproject and drop all files in folder "public" in "www"
3: (Delete public) Now index.php edit and modify two lignes and add "myproject" DIR__.'/monProjet/vendor/autoload.php';
4: Finish

I try a lot on thinks on .htaccess but i have not found :(

Thanks for you'r help, and i have one question and is maybe my problem in myproject/public i have no .htacess before the upload. So is created when ?

Ir the code of first time is working ( i do exactly same )
 index.php

```
/*** Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
*
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/myProject/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/myProject/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

The .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] e</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please, please, PLEASE just put the code in here. Screenshots via your phone camera is a silly way to share code. (So is editing code in Microsoft Word. Get a code editor!)

Comment: Also, from your folder structure, that's not Laravel.

Comment: I have edit that. I have create with laravel and adding vuejs to him

Answer (score 0):

In your www/.htaccess , Change

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi ! thanks but Nothing change i got the same error :( idk why before all working good

Answer (score 0):

So i really don't know what happend i retry for the thousand time.

I juste drop all file in public in main and let my folder "myProject" in main too.
Like every time. But is work ... so i don't understand what is going one.

Thanks for help